# Volume of revolution x-axis

Tags: calculus

Use the shell method to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the line $y=6x+7$ and the parabola $y=x^2$ around the $x$-axis

I'm getting the wrong answer.

I read somewhere that you have to solve for $x$ and then subtract one equation from the other and multiply by $y$ to get the integral, which has the limits of the zeros on $y$

$$2\pi\int_{1}^{49}y\left(\frac{y-7}{6}-\sqrt{y}\right)$$

doesn't seem to be getting me $\frac{15872\pi}{5}$

Comment: Are you sure you are rotating around the $x$-axis? That $\sqrt{y}$ looks very odd to me.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the representative rectangle for volume of revolution is parallel to the x-axis, so $\sqrt{y}$ is correct

Comment: Well I solved y=x^2 for x.

Comment: @VarunIyer: [...] is parallel to the $x$-axis if you're rotating around the $y$-axis, that is not the case.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I realize that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be solved using the **Disk Method** (**Washer method** really). The shell method wouldn't work here.

So you're integrating with respect with x,

so your bounds would be the range of x values.

Setting the two equations equal to one another gives us that:

$$x = -1, 7$$

Now, you're subtracting the two volumes,

The first one is:

$$\pi\int_{-1}^{7} (6x+7)^2dx $$

And the second one is:

$$\pi\int_{-1}^{7} (x^2)^2dx$$

So we subtract these to get:

$$\pi\int_{-1}^{7}\left((6x+7)^2-(x^2)^2\right)dx$$

which equals the answer you stated above.

Comment: Well, the question specified the shell method. So thats frustrating. But I guess if I get the right answer it doesn't matter if I use the washer method instead.

Comment: The problem is the shell method is more tedious because you have to find the bounds in terms of $y$ and set the equations in terms of $y$. This is a simple integral that can be done using the washer method.

Answer (score 1):

Just using the [Cavalieri's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle), the volume is given by:
$$\pi\int_{-1}^{7}\left((6x+7)^2-(x^2)^2\right)dx = \frac{15872}{5}\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

The shell method can work, but you need to be careful with how you set it up, and I expect that was the purpose of the question.

For each y value, we consider the range of x values within the region. When 1 < y < 49, this is (y - 7)/6 < x < SQRT(y), but for 0 < y < 1 it's SQRT (y) < x < SQRT(y), so you have to integrate separately for y values 0 to 1 and 1 to 49